# How to find is process blocking other process

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres 12+ query

```
select pid, 
  pg_blocking_pids(pid) AS blocking_pids 
from pg_stat_activity
```

returns blocking processes for every process.

[image]

How to add one more column to this query which is true when process blocks other processes, e.q its pid is in any blocking_pids column array.

In sample result row with pid 7968 should have value true. and all other rows should have false value.

I tried

```
select pid, 
  pid in pg_blocking_pids() AS isblocking,
  pg_blocking_pids(pid) AS blocking_pids 
from pg_stat_activity
```

but this causes error since `pg_blocking_pids()` requires process argument.
Postgres 12 and 13 servers are used.

Comment: you'll probably need a sub-query for that

Comment: ´pg_blocking_pids()´ returns array. How to check is pid in any arrary returned by  ´pg_blocking_pids()´ for any process. Mabe there is some method in 12+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. It runs your query as a CTE, the a main query does a lateral self join with the CTE looking for the PID in the resulting array from  pg_blocking_pids function.

```
with blockers(pid,blocking_pids) as 
     (select pid  
           , pg_blocking_pids(pid)  
        from pg_stat_activity
     ) 
select b1.pid, b1.blocking_pids, s1.blocker
  from blockers b1 
  left join lateral ( select 'Yes' blocker  
                       from blockers b2
                      where b1.pid = any (b2.blocking_pids)
            ) s1 
         on true;
```

I cannot demonstrate the full query as on my laptop I am not like to have a blocking. But I can [simulate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dbe1a547efa3c49a347746e5a2f3e706) it with a couple rows from your data.